# Android autofocus

Tags: android, highlight, android-imageview

I am new to android and just created an android application consisting of many images and a few buttons suppose like john, what I want is whenever a person clicks on john, all the images with names including john will get highlighted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific - there's nothing to go from here... Also, your title is very misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for exmple of Jhon:

Just follow the steps:

1)`setOnItemClickListener` on images

from that you find all about the selected image throgh function get `getResources()`
 you can fetch the name from that.

2)After fetchting the name fire one query like "selected name "
   it should display result name "Jhon"

3)Display name picture as per your requirement.
    or
4)If you want to display into the same you can

let me know if you have any query for it.

Comment: Did you get your own solution  ?or my solution helped you ?